# how to not affect the others drop shadow in shapes or layers when changing on a current layers or shapes dropshadow

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs4

I have a problem in photoshop, Im designing a website and came across in adding drop shadow for some effects reason however whenever I change the angle of dropshadow of an angle or layer, the other dropshadow is affecting or changing as well, How can i make it not to affect others or the other dropshadow style pr keep the angle of a dropshadow of others layers or shapes whenever i change the angle of my current shape or layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck the box for "Use Global Light" in the drop shadow dialog box. It's checked off by default so that all drop shadows change at once. If you uncheck that option, you will only change the drop shadow for the active shape.